# R mathematical annotations

Tags: r, annotations, plotmath

I have a problem inserting a vertical line in a mathematical annotation. I have search through the annotation symbols without luck.

I would like to put a mathematical annotation containing conditional probability sign (|) in the x-label of a plot. What I would like is the expression p(x_j | o_i) where "j" and "i" are subscripts.

I have the following construction

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression( paste("Likelihood, p" * (y[i] %up% o[j])) ))
```

and I wold like to substitute the arrow with a vertical line.
Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets you "there" (for some definition of "there"):

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression("Likelihood, p" * (y[i] ~ "|" ~ o[j])))
```

[image: plotmath axis label]

Answer (score 4):

This is not intended to be the answer for the OP. It seems that many people enjoy playing with the `plotmath` hacks in R, but the [`tikzDevice`](http://cran.r-project.org/package=tikzDevice) package has given us a decent solution for this type of problems: you can write native LaTeX expressions in R plots. Then [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/) makes the learning curve less steep. Below is what you can achieve with R (much better quality than `plotmath`):

[image: tikz graphics from tikzDevice and kntir]

The full Rnw source (save it as, say, `test.Rnw`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
<<likelihood, fig.width=4, fig.height=2.5, dev='tikz'>>=
par(mar = c(4.5, 4, .1, .1))
plot(1:10, xlab = 'Likelihood, $p(y_{i}|o_{j})$')
@
\end{document}
```

Then

```
install.packages(c('knitr', 'tikzDevice'))
library(knitr)
knit('test.Rnw')
```

You will have a PDF file named `figure/likelihood.pdf` which is the plot above. See Figure 9 in the [graphics manual](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-graphics.pdf) and Page 7 in the [main manual](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf) of the `knitr` package for more examples. LaTeX is required to compile tikz to PDF.